# Call a method inside an anonymous class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to clarify a question about the anonym class in typescript. I have a code, like this:

```
class A {

    constructor() {
        let b = new class extends B {

            run() {
                method(); // how to call that method here?
            }
        }
    }

    method(): void {

    }
}

interface B {

    run(): void;
}
```

Actually, I can store a reference of class A through 'this' variable, but not sure that is the right way. Anyways how is correct to call a method inside run?

Comment: `const a = this; let b = new class { run() { a.method(); } }` is how you write that. No to the removal of the `extends` clause which is an error in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can store a reference to the enclosing class instance, and then use that reference to call its method:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELIN4FgBQzlQCuIAFAJQBcyAbgPbAAmA3LgL664IA2cAzr8gCCmXPgS0QvMEQRhaUciLz5k4yWGS8IXGMgC8yMAAtgvFsvxcIGgEb7kICAHdVPfsmABbAA5XPEcAF0bAsVIlIyJRVozW0YADp-Y1oGcnMY5HZQrPws0WQkoxTyKjpGTCysoA)

```ts
interface B {
  run(): void;
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    const self = this;
    let b = new class implements B {
      run() {
        self.method();
      }
    }
  }

  method(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is ok, but any idea to do this in a different way?

Comment: @user2936296 What do you mean by "a different way"? What is the exact criteria?

Comment: I mean without 'const self = this;'

Comment: @user2936296 If you don't like `self`, you can use another variable name.

Comment: I know that I can change a variable, I am trying to find another approach.

Comment: @user2936296 What's prevents that approach from solving your issue?